# Rotating a matrix in the direction of a vector?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, 3d, glm-math

I have a player in the shape of a sphere that can move around freely in the directions x and z.
The players current speed is stored in a vector that is added to the players position on every frame:

```
m_position += m_speed;
```

I also have a rotation matrix that I'd like to rotate in the direction that the player's moving in (imagine how a ball would rotate if it rolled on the floor).
Here's a short video to help visualise the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vzV3.jpg

Notice in the video when I start moving up and down (Z) as opposed to left and right (X) the rotation axis no longer matches the player's movement.

Code used to produce the results:

```
glm::vec3 UP = glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
float rollSpeed = fabs(m_Speed.x + m_Speed.z);
if (rollSpeed > 0.0f) {
    m_RotationMatrix = glm::rotate(m_RotationMatrix, rollSpeed, glm::cross(UP, glm::normalize(m_Speed)));
}
```

Thankful for help

Comment: rotation needs two things: a rotation axis and a direction to rotate. When you say "rotate matrix in the direction of a vector", do you maybe mean a rotation with the vector as rotation axis?

Comment: @tobi303 Maybe my question wasn't very clear. Basically I'm trying to figure out the correct axis to use when rotating the matrix, given the players current speed.

Comment: maybe a small drawing may help to illustrate the problem

Comment: I edited my question and added a gif of the failed results  (http://imgur.com/YrTG2al)

Comment: Shouldn't `rollSpeed` be the size of the speed vector `sqrt(m_Speed.x * m_Speed.x + m.Speed.z * m.Speed.z)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rollSpeed` computation is wrong -- e.g., if the signs of `m_Speed.x` and `m_Speed.z` speed are different, they will *subtract*.  You need to use the norm of the speed in the plane:

```
float rollSpeed = sqrt(m_Speed.x * m_Speed.x + m_Speed.y * m_Speed.y);
```

To be more general about it, you can re-use your cross product instead.  That way, your math is less likely to get out of sync -- something like:

```
glm::vec3 rollAxis = glm::cross(UP, m_speed);
float rollSpeed = glm::length(rollAxis);
m_RotationMatrix = glm::rotate(m_RotationMatrix, rollSpeed, rollAxis);
```

Comment: You're right about rollSpeed being calculated wrong, although I think the issue shown that I demonstrated in the video lies in the calculation of the rollAxis (cross(UP, m_Speed)). Maybe "up" should vary based on the sphere's current rotation

Comment: You did not say how you are using the matrix, but seems possible that you are either using it the wrong way, updating the matrix from the wrong end, or something comparable.  Check your assumptions about your coordinate systems;  e.g., you may need to use the inverse of `m_RotationMatrix` to rotate your sphere.

Comment: inversing the matrix worked. This is how I use the rotation matrix:

`glm::mat4 model;


    model = glm::translate(model, m_Position) * glm::inverse(m_RotationMatrix);


    // set model uniform in shader`

Answer (score 0):

`rollSpeed` should be the size of the speed vector.

```
float rollSpeed = glm::length(m_Speed);
```

The matrix transform expects an angle. The angle of rotation will depend on the size of your ball. But say it's radius `r` then the angle (in radians) you need is

```
angle = rollSpeed/r;
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly you need a matrix rotation which would work in any axis  direction(x,y,z).

I think you should write a `rotate()` method per axis (x, y, z), also you should  point to direction on which axis your direction points, you should write `direction.x`  or `direction.y` or  `direction.z`  and  rotation  matrix  will understand  to where the  direction vector is being  point.

Comment: If I understand you correctly (which is kinda hard, please respect capitalization and full words) you suggest to write an if-clause for each direction. This is exactly what the code above is doing by using the cross product, just in more general way, working with arbitrary directions in the xz-plane.

Comment: No no no who  said  that  if clause  is required ?! above  code does  only what   author says  , when  he is  changing  vector direction  code does  not work.  I  think  that he should be more  specific per axis direction  for which  direction  vector  is pointing.  This is my opinion.

Comment: @BDL " I tried the following which works until you try to move in a different direction from the one you've previously moved in. (x to z or vice versa)"  Quotation from post  author.